# jQuery finding next class outside div and toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

rather new to jquery and having an issue where i want to toggle a class on the closest class i request.

Code example below, any ideas what im doing wrong here?

```js
// more info functions
$('.popup').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.popup-input').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_1_Popup" name="PC_Row_1_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="hidden popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_2_Popup" name="PC_Row_2_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="hidden popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_3_Popup" name="PC_Row_3_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="hidden popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_4_Popup" name="PC_Row_4_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="hidden popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">
```

Comment: You are wrongly accessing closest. Need to add Div in input element then have to find inside that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parent()` to move up to the parent div then use `next('.popup-input')` to target the next element with class `popup-input` and finally toggle class using `toggleClass()`, check example bellow.

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.popup').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.popup-input').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_1_Popup" name="PC_Row_1_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_2_Popup" name="PC_Row_2_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_3_Popup" name="PC_Row_3_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="PC_Row_4_Popup" name="PC_Row_4_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.popup').closest('.poput-input')
```

will give you the closest ancestor while traversing upwards.

You can use

```
$(this).parent().next('.popup-input');
```

to traverse(downwards) to the next popup-input in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle with your javascript code snippet as well. You need to change your JS and HTML code a bit.

```
// more info functions
$('.popup').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.column').find('.popup-input').toggleClass('hidden');
});

<div class="column medium">
  <div class="icon info popup">link</div>
  <div class="icon more"></div>
  <input type="text" id="PC_Row_1_Popup" name="PC_Row_1_Popup" value="" placeholder="More info description" class="popup-input form-control ccm-input-text">
</div>
```